For a compact sober "highly non-$T_1$" space, how much "highly connectedness" is needed to imply it's a spectral space?
This is intended to be a self-answering question, which is allowed on StackExchange sites (see here).
Before starting with the question, here are some relevant definitions and background information:
First, "highly connectedness" properties: A topological space $X$ is called hereditarily connected if all its subspaces are connected; equivalently, if its collection of open sets is linearly ordered by inclusion; equivalently, if its collection of closed sets is linearly ordered by inclusion. It is called ultraconnected if any two nonempty closed sets intersect. It is called irreducible, or hyperconnected, if any two nonempty open sets intersect. One easily observes that hereditarily connected spaces are both hyperconnected and ultraconnected.
A point $x \in X$ is called a generic point if $\overline{\{x\}} = X$; equivalently, if all nonempty open sets contain $x$. We observe that a space with a generic point is necessarily hyperconnected. A point $x \in X$ is called a focal point if its only neighborhood is $X$; equivalently, if all nonempty closed sets contain $x$. We observe that a space with a focal point is necessarily both ultraconnected and compact. In fact, for a nonempty space $X$, being compact and ultraconnected is equivalent to having a focal point. See, for example, here.
We recall that the specialization preorder on the topological space $X$ is defined s.t. $x \leq y$ iff $x \in \overline{\{y\}}$. Two points are topologically indistinguishable iff they are equivalent under the specialization preorder, so $X$ is $T_0$ iff the specialization preorder is a partial order. We also note that $X$ is $T_1$ iff the specialization preorder is trivial.
We observe that generic points can also be characterized as maximums of the specialization preorder, and focal points can be characterized as minimums of the specialization preorder. Moreover, hereditarily connected spaces are exactly those spaces whose specialization preorders are total, so hereditarily connected $T_0$ spaces are exactly those spaces whose specialization preorders are linear orders.
A topological space $X$ is Alexandrov iff arbitrary intersections of open sets are open; equivalently, iff arbitrary unions of closed sets are closed; equivalently, iff every point has a unique minimum open neighborhood. Alexandrov topologies on a set $X$ are in one-to-one correspondence with preorders on $X$: For any preorder $\leq$ on $X$, it generates an Alexandrov topology on $X$ by declaring open sets to be exactly upwards closed sets under $\leq$; equivalently, by declaring closed sets to be exactly downwards closed sets under $\leq$. Conversely, given any Alexandrov topology on $X$, we may obtain a preorder by simply choosing the specialization preorder.
Moving on to concepts related to spectral spaces: A topological space $X$ is called quasi-sober if every nonempty closed irreducible subspace of $X$ has at least one generic point. It is called sober if every nonempty closed irreducible subspace of $X$ has a unique generic point. We remark that being sober is equivalent to being quasi-sober and $T_0$. Finally, $X$ is called spectral if it is compact and sober, the intersection of any two compact open sets is compact, and the collection of compact open sets forms a base for the topology. We remark that spectral spaces are exactly prime spectra of bounded distributive lattices, and are also exactly prime spectra of commutative rings.

The inspiration for this question comes from the following thereom recorded on pi-Base: A hereditarily connected, Alexandrov, compact, and sober space is automatically spectral. We briefly remark on the proof here: Given two compact open sets $U, V$, since the space is hereditarily connected, one of the two must be contained in the other, so $U \cap V$ is either $U$ or $V$, and thus compact. Being Alexandrov implies compact opens form a base. Indeed, the minimum open neighborhood of any given point $x$ has a focal point, namely $x$, so it is compact. Clearly, all such minimum open neighborhoods form a base.
While researching on pi-Base, we see that there are no counterexamples known to pi-Base if the hereditarily connected and Alexandrov conditions in the theorem are weakened. Indeed, there is currently no space $X$ known to pi-Base as hyperconnected, compact, and sober, but not spectral (see here). Neither is there any example known to pi-Base as ultraconnected, compact, and sober, but not spectral (see here). This naturally yields the following questions:

Is it the case that either hyperconnected or ultraconnected, without Alexandrov, is already enough to imply a compact sober space is spectral? That is, if $X$ is either hyperconnected, compact, and sober; or ultraconnected, compact, and sober, is $X$ necessarily spectral?
If the answer to $1$ is no, then can the hereditarily connected condition be weakened at all? In the extreme case, if $X$ is hyperconnected, ultraconnected, Alexandrov, compact, and sober, is $X$ necessarily spectral?
Again, if the answer to $1$ is no, what if we remove the Alexandrov condition without weakening the hereditarily connected condition? That is, if $X$ is hereditarily connected, compact, and sober, is $X$ necessarily spectral?
If the answer to $3$ is no, are there some extra conditions that can ensure hereditarily connected, compact, and sober spaces are spectral? In particular, if $X$ is hereditarily connected, compact, and sober, and furthermore $|X| < \mathfrak{c}$, is this enough to imply $X$ is spectral? (The motivation for the condition $|X| < \mathfrak{c}$ will become clear in the answer to $3$.)


The answer to $1$ is no. In fact, there is a space listed on pi-Base that is a counterexample: the overlapping interval topology. The space has underlying set $[-1, 1]$ and nonempty open sets are of the form,
$$(a,b) \cap [-1, 1], \text{ for }a < 0 < b$$
$X$ has a generic point $0$, so it is hyperconnected. It is compact since any open neighborhood of $-1$ will cover $[-1, 0]$ while any open neighborhood of $1$ will cover $[0, 1]$. It is clearly $T_0$. It is sober as one can easily check that nonempty closed irreducible subsets of $X$ are exactly of the form,
$$[-1, a], \text{ for }-1 \leq a < 0; [b, 1], \text{ for }0 < b \leq 1; \text{ or }X$$
All have unique generic points: $a$ for $[-1,a]$, $b$ for $[b,1]$, and $0$ for $X$. Finally, it is not spectral - $X$ only has two compact open sets: $\varnothing$ and $X$, which certainly do not form a base. Indeed, let $a < 0 < b$. If $a \geq -1$, then $(a,b)\cap[-1,1]$ is not compact as,
$$(a,b)\cap[-1,1] = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty ((a_n,b)\cap[-1,1])$$
where $a_n$ is a sequence of negative numbers strictly decreasing to $a$. But $(a,b)\cap[-1,1]$ is not the union of any finitely many open sets on the RHS. Similarly, $(a,b)\cap[-1,1]$ is not compact when $b \leq 1$.

However, the above example does not answer $2$. Indeed, the overlapping interval topology is neither ultraconnected - $[-1, -\frac{1}{2}]$ and $[\frac{1}{2}, 1]$ are two disjoint nonempty closed sets; nor is it Alexandrov - $\{0\} = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty (-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n})$ is not open. Here, we construct a space $X$ that is hyperconnected, ultraconnected, Alexandrov, compact, and sober, but not spectral, showing that the hereditarily connected condition in the theorem referenced in the question cannot be weakened at all.
Consider the set $\{\frac{1}{n}\}_{n=1}^\infty$ with its usual order. Let,
$$X=\{-1,0_a,0_b\}\cup\{\frac{1}{n}\}_{n=1}^\infty$$
where either of the zeros is smaller than all $\frac{1}{n}$, the two zeros are incomparable, and $-1$ is smaller than everything else. Take the Alexandrov topology on $X$. $X$ is hyperconnected since the ordering on $X$ is upward directed. It is ultraconnected since the ordering is also downward directed. It is compact since $-1$ is a focal point. $X$ is clearly $T_0$. Closed sets are downward closed sets, so nonempty closed sets are exactly,
$$\{-1\};\{-1,0_a\}; \{-1,0_b\}; \{-1,0_a,0_b\}; \{-1,0_a,0_b\}\cup\{\frac{1}{n}\}_{n=N}^\infty, \text{ for }N\geq 1$$
$\{-1,0_a,0_b\}$ is not irreducible as $\{0_a\}$ and $\{0_b\}$ are both open in $\{-1,0_a,0_b\}$. All other nonempty closed sets are irreducible, and they all have maximum elements, which are generic points. Thus, $X$ is sober.
However, $X$ is not spectral, because $\{0_a\} \cup \{\frac{1}{n}\}_{n=1}^\infty$ and $\{0_b\} \cup \{\frac{1}{n}\}_{n=1}^\infty$ are both compact open (they both have minimum elements and thus focal points). But their intersection, $\{\frac{1}{n}\}_{n=1}^\infty$, is not compact.

The answer to $3$ is no as well. Indeed, consider the right open ray topology on $X = [0,1]$, i.e., the open sets are $X$ and $(a,1]$ for $0\leq a\leq 1$. $X$ is clearly hereditarily connected. It is compact because $0$ is a focal point. It is clearly $T_0$. Nonempty closed sets are of the form $[0,a]$ for $0\leq a\leq 1$, which has $a$ as unique generic point, so $X$ is sober. It is, however, not spectral. By essentially the same reasoning as in the overlapping interval topology, $(a,1]$ is never compact unless $a=1$ (i.e., when $(a,1]=\varnothing$), so the only compact open sets are $\varnothing$ and $X$, which clearly do not form a basis.

The motivation for the $|X| < \mathfrak{c}$ condition in $4$ is due to the fact that the counterexample for $3$ has cardinality continuum, whereas the counterexample for $2$ is countable. It is thus natural to ask if a counterexample for $3$ that is countable (or at least has cardinality less than continuum) exists. We show here that no such counterexample exists, i.e.,
Theorem: Any hereditarily connected, compact, sober $X$ with $|X| < \mathfrak{c}$ is spectral.
The result is trivially true when $X$ is empty, so we'll assume $X \neq \varnothing$. We start by noting that, as $X$ is sober, it is $T_0$. As it is hereditarily connected, we then have the specialization preorder $\leq$ on $X$ is a linear order. We note that $\leq$ is bounded. Indeed, as $X$ is hereditarily connected, it is irreducible, so as $X$ is sober, it has a generic point, i.e., a maximum of $\leq$. As $X$ is hereditarily connected, it is ultraconnected, so as $X$ is compact, it has a focal point, i.e., a minimum of $\leq$. We'll write the minimum of $\leq$ as $0$ and the maximum of $\leq$ as $1$.
Furthermore, since any subset of a hereditarily connected space is hereditarily connected and thus irreducible, by $X$ being sober, any nonempty closed $K \subset X$ must have a generic point, i.e., $K$ has a maximum. We note that by definition of the specialization preorder, any closed $K \subset X$ must be downwards closed. Thus, any nonempty closed $K \subset X$ is of the form $[0,x]$ for some $x \in X$. Moreover, we note that any $[0,x]$ is in fact closed, since it is $\overline{\{x\}}$ by definition of the specialization preorder.
Lemma: Any nonempty subset $A \subset X$ has an infimum.
Proof: Since $[0,a]$ is closed and contains $0$ for all $a \in A$, $K = \bigcap_{a \in A} [0,a]$ is a nonempty closed set, so it is of the form $[0,x]$ for some $x \in X$. Note that $K$ is exactly the set of all lower bounds of $A$, so $x = \inf(A)$. $\square$
Note that this also implies any nonempty subset $A \subset X$ has a supremum, since $\sup(A)$ is exactly the infimum of the set of upper bounds of $A$ (which is nonempty as $1$ is an upper bound to any $A$).
Lemma: There is no subset $A \subset X$ s.t. $\leq|_A$ is a nontrivial dense order.
Proof: Assume to the contrary that such an $A$ exists. It is easy to see that there is then a further subset $B \subset A$ which is countably infinite and $\leq|_B$ is a dense linear order with no endpoints. In particular, $(B, \leq|_B) \cong (\mathbb{Q}, \leq_\mathbb{Q})$. Let $\pi: (\mathbb{Q}, \leq_\mathbb{Q}) \to (B, \leq|_B)$ be an order-isomorphism. We now define an order-embedding $\phi: (\mathbb{R}, \leq_\mathbb{R}) \to (X, \leq)$ as follows:
$$\phi(r) = \sup\{\pi(q):q \in \mathbb{Q}, q < r\}$$
It is not hard to check that this is indeed an order-embedding. But this is a contradiction as $|X| < \mathfrak{c}$. $\square$
Lemma: Compact open sets in $X$ form a base for the topology.
Proof: Let $U \subset X$ be nonempty open and $x \in U$. By definition of the specialization preorder, open subsets must be upwards closed. Thus, if $[x,1]$ is open, then $[x,1] \subset U$. Furthermore, $x$ is a focal point of $[x,1]$, so it is compact. If $[x,1]$ is not open, then $U$ must contain some $y < x$. The order on the set $[y,x]$ then cannot be dense by the previous lemma, so there must exist some $y \leq z_1 < z_2 \leq x$ s.t. there are no points strictly between $z_1$ and $z_2$. Note that the set $(z_1, 1]$ is open, as its complement $[0,z_1]$ is closed. But $(z_1,1] = [z_2,1]$, so $[z_2,1]$ is a compact open set containing $x$. Furthermore, as $y \in U$ and $y < z_2$, we have $[z_2,1] \subset U$. In either case, we have obtained a compact open set containing $x$ and contained in $U$, so the result follows. $\square$
As has already been observed in the question, being hereditarily connected already implies the intersection of two compact open sets is compact. Thus, $X$ is spectral.

For the sake of possible future reference, here is some additional theory building regarding hereditarily connected $T_0$ spaces. Fix a linear order $\leq$ on a nonempty set $X$. Any topology whose specialization preorder is $\leq$ has to satisfy two properties:

Since $(\leftarrow, x] = \overline{\{x\}}$ is closed, $(x, \to)$ is open for all $x \in X$;
Any open set is upwards closed under $\leq$.

It is not hard to check that any topology satisfying above two properties will have $\leq$ as its specialization preorder as well. Thus, there is a minimum topology compatible with $\leq$, namely, the right open ray topology, generated by the base $\{(x, \to):x\in X\}$. There is also a maximum topology compatible with $\leq$, namely, the Alexandrov topology associated to $\leq$, whose open sets are exactly upwards closed sets; equivalently, the right closed ray topology, generated by the base $\{[x, \to):x\in X\}$. Then, a topology on $X$ has $\leq$ as its specialization preorder iff it is finer than the right open ray topology and coarser than the right closed ray topology. Note that all such topologies are hereditarily connected and $T_0$.
Let us record here what various properties mentioned above correspond to in this context. We will not write down full proofs here, but it is easy to adapt various parts of the proof of the theorem above to prove all the following:

Alexandrov: The topology is maximum, i.e., the right closed ray topology.
Compact: $\leq$ has a minimum.
Sober: Every nonempty $A \subset X$ has a supremum under $\leq$; equivalently, $\leq$ has a maximum and every nonempty $A \subset X$ that is bounded below has an infimum. Moreover, the topology is minimum, i.e., the right open ray topology.
Compact open sets form a base: The topology is "large enough", i.e., for every $y < x$ in $X$, there is $z \in X$ with $y < z \leq x$ and $[z, \to)$ is open; equivalently, the collection of all $x$ for which $[x, \to)$ is open is dense in the upper limit topology (i.e., the topology generated by the subbase $\{(\leftarrow, x]:x\in X\} \cup \{(y, \to):y\in X\}$).
Spectral: $\leq$ is bounded. Moreover, every nonempty $A \subset X$ has a supremum under $\leq$; equivalently, every nonempty $A \subset X$ has an infimum. Moreover, the set of elements with immediate predecessors, together with the minimum of $\leq$, is dense in the upper limit topology; equivalently, for every $y < x$ in $X$, there is $z \in X$ with $y < z \leq x$ and $z$ has an immediate predecessor. Moreover, the topology is minimum, i.e., the right open ray topology.
Minimum and maximum topologies coincide: Every $x \in X$ is either the minimum of $\leq$, or has an immediate predecessor.
Compact + Sober + Alexandrov: $\leq$ is bounded and every nonempty $A \subset X$ has a maximum, i.e., $\leq$ is the reverse ordering on a successor ordinal. In this case the minimum and maximum topologies coincide (the immediate predecessor of $x \in X$ which is not the minimum of $\leq$ is simply given by $\max\{y\in X: y < x\}$). This also shows why "Compact + Sober + Alexandrov => Spectral".


Beautiful presentation and very nice result!
